# How to deploy laravel site on hosting

Tags: laravel, deployment, hosting

I have a dilemma. I have a laravel website and want to deploy it on hosting.
Let me first describe the structure of hosting.
There is root directory (/). Under the root directory there are 3 maps.

mywebsite.com (/)

httpd.private
httpd.www
tmp

I moved my project to httpd.www because it is similar to public_html. Now when I try to access mywebsite.com website does not work. It is only visible when I type mywebsite.com/public but that's not what I want. I want to see the website when I enter mywebsite.com.

Can someone help me please?

I tried a lot of things to change but it is impossible for me and now I don't know how to solve this issue

Comment: which server you use ?

Comment: what do you mean? which hosting do I use?

Comment: Did you take a look at your webserver configuration? Did you update the public path in your webserver configuration? It is probably pointing to the wrong folder so you need to update the configuration and restart your server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:**

You have to put your laravel folder itself outside of your www directory

- httpd.private
- httpd.www
- tmp
- laravel

**Step 2**
If you dont have SSH access

Copy your laravel/public folder (the contents, not the folder itself) to the httpd.www folder. Then in your http.www/pubic folder, open index.php and change the paths to the correct path.

```
line 34: require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
line 47: $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**Step 2** If you have ssh access

```
rm -rf httpd.www
ln -s laravel/public httpd.www
```